# Loop works, get error when trying map-reduce

Tags: swift, mapreduce

I'm new to map-reduce and wanted to play around with it a bit. I hope this question isn't too stupid.

I have this code working:

```
var str = "Geometry add to map: "
for element in geometryToAdd {
     str.append(element.toString())
}
print(str)
```

Now I wanted to play around with map-reduce since I learned it recently. I rewrote it as this:

```
print(geometryToAdd.reduce("Geometry add to map: ", {$0.append($1.toString())}))
```

This gives me an error `error: MyPlayground.playground:127:57: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. What do I do wrong?

```
var geometryToAdd: Array<Geometry> = []
```

and the class `Geometry` has a `toString` function.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two similar methods:

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
func reduce<Result>(into initialResult: Result, _ updateAccumulatingResult: (inout Result, Element) throws -> ()) rethrows -> Result
```

You are using the first version, where `$0` is immutable and the closure
must return the accumulated value. This does not compile because
`append()` modifies its receiver.

Using the second version makes it compile: Here `$0` is mutable and 
the closure updates `$0` with the accumulated value.

```
print(geometryToAdd.reduce(into: "Geometry add to map: ", {$0.append($1.toString())}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it less ambiguous :

```
print(geometryToAdd.reduce("Geometry add to map: ", {
      $0 + $1.toString()
}))
```

The error comes from the fact that you can only `append()` to a variable sequence : `$0` is an immutable `String`. In the loop, `str` was mutable : a `var`, not a `let`.

Have a look at the signature of `reduce`

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

`nextPartialResult` is a function/closure that takes two arguments and gives a result. The arguments of this function are immutable, they are not `inout` parameters. Only `inout` parameters can be modified.

Find out more on function parameter immutability [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) :

> Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the
>   value of a function parameter from within the body of that function
>   results in a compile-time error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer as well. The only reason that I gave martin R the checkmark and not you is because he solved it with append as it was used in the question, but your explanation was also very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using `joined(separator:)` instead of reduce. It has better performance, and lets you put in a separator, if you wish:

```
print("Geometry add to map: \(geometryToAdd.map(String.init).joined(separator: "")")
```